# hermeneutics of God of gods

Tags: god

What is the hermeneutics of the Bible verses that mention "God of gods"?

Salm 136:2  give thanks unto the **God of gods**: for his mercy endureth for ever.

Deuteronomy 10:17: For the Lord your God is **God of gods** and Lord of lords, the great God, mighty and awesome, who shows no partiality and accepts no bribes.

may we deduce that are there minor gods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Bible text of Deuteronomy 10:17 is part of the consistent theme that there is only ever the one true God, with all other named gods being false gods, man-made gods, pseudo-gods, would-be gods.

The Old Testament never denies the fact that humans throughout the centuries have created ideas of gods other than the one true God, with some being presented as usurper gods, claiming to be the one and only Creator God, when they don't even exist, except in the imaginations and carvings of humans who are in rebellion against their Creator.

A biblical deduction would agree with the prophets of old who wrote such things as:

> "For thus saith the Lord that created the heavens; God himself that
> formed the earth and made it; ...I am the Lord, and there is none
> else... Assemble yourselves and come; draw near together, ye escaped
> of the nations: they have no knowledge that set up the wood of their
> graven images, and pray unto a god that cannot save... and there is no
> God else beside me; a just God and a Saviour; there is none beside me.
> Look unto me, and be ye saved, all the ends of the earth: for I am God
> and there is none else." Isaiah 46:18-22 A.V., with more in chapter 45.
>
> "Thus saith the Lord the King of Israel, and his redeemer the Lord of
> hosts; I am the first, and I am the last; and beside me there is no
> God... Is there a god beside me? yea, there is no God: I know not any.
> They that make a graven image are all of them vanity, and their
> delectable things shall not profit; and they are their own witnesses;
> they see not, nor know, that they may be ashamed. Who hath formed a
> god, or molten a graven image that is profitable for nothing?" [and so
> on to verse 20] A.V.

**There are no minor gods in the realms of deity.** The word 'gods' is sometimes used to apply to humans who are appointed as judges, who represent God the Judge in the nation of Israel. But deity is never ascribed to them. They are to be respected, but never to be venerated or bowed down to. When the term 'gods' is applied to them (as in Psalm 82:6, quoted by Jesus in John 10:34 to rebuke those who would not give him due respect as God's anointed and appointed one on Earth) it is never with any idea of them having divine being. It is their role in the society of God's people that is referred to.

**EDIT in view of the fact of henotheism:**
There is no denying that the Israelites sometimes fell into henotheistic practices, considering some of the gods of the pagans to be worthy of worship alongside their worship of Yahweh. They tried to justify this by claiming to give lesser worship to those 'minor' deities than they did to Yahweh. But just as only giving some love to God violates the principle of whole-souled love for God, meaning the person does not love God at all (from his point of view), so 'sharing' worship of God with that of other deities violates the principle of his command, "Thou halt have no other gods before me." Sinful humans are inclined to hedge their bets with such practices, but God will have none of it; total love, total worship, exclusive devotion to the one and only true God. That is why Jeremiah recorded what God said on the matter, in the texts copied above. He recognises no other gods.

Further, Jeremiah also penned how the Israelites who were trying to hedge their bets back then, were blind to how their henotheism was bringing God's curse upon them. God's prophets knew full well that the people were convinced those other gods were real. In chapter 44 he addressed the remnant left in the land, after God had desolated Judah for its idolatry. Those people were set on fleeing to Egypt despite God telling them to stay put. They were so determined, the took Jeremiah captive with them when they fled. He wrote this:

> "Then all the men which knew that their wives had burned incense unto
> other gods, and all the women that stood by, a great multitude, even
> all the people that dwelt in the land of Egypt, in Pathros, answered
> Jeremiah, saying, 'As for the word that thou hast spoken unto us in
> the name of the Lord, we will not hearken unto thee. But we will
> certainly do whatsoever thing goeth forth out of our own mouth, to
> burn incense unto the queen of heaven, and to pour out drink offerings
> unto her, as we have done, we, and our fathers, our kings, and our
> princes, in the cities of Judah, and in the streets of Jerusalem: for
> then we had plenty of victuals. ad were well, an d saw no evil. But
> since we have left off to burn incense to the queen of heaven, and to
> pour out drink offerings unto her, we have wanted all things, and gave
> been consumed by the sword and by the famine. And when we burned
> incense to the queen of heaven, and poured out drink offerings unto
> her, did we make her cakes to worship her and pour out drink offerings
> unto her, without our men?' Jeremiah 44:15-19 A.V.

Jeremiah then told all the Israelites who had given him that answer that it was ***because*** they'd done that in the past that God had now devastated their nation!

> "So that the Lord could no longer bear, because of the evil of your
> doings, and because of the abominations which ye have committed;
> therefore is your land a desolation, and an astonishment, and a curse,
> without an inhabitant, as at this day. Because you have burned
> incense... therefore this evil has happened unto you.." vss. 22-23

He then pronounced God's further judgment on those who fled to Egypt that they would die in Egypt, for God would cause Pharaoh,his armies, and all the people to be crushed.

Such was the conviction of those Israelites who fled to Egypt to continue their idolatrous worship of false gods there, they could not see that that was had got them into their mess in the first place. But, no! They said it was due to ***stopping*** such idol worship that they had been crushed, so they would resume that worship in the land that promoted idolatry Big Time - Egypt. Of course they believed their queen of heaven was mighty to save! They staked their lives on that conviction - and died for it.

There's no need to go to scholars to see how henotheism had, at many times, a grip on the people who were in covenant with God to worship him alone - the Bible is full of that! Just read all that Jeremiah wrote on the subject. For sure they believed their false gods would save them. Nobody who devotes such time, money and adoration to idols doubts but their idols are real!

Comment: +1. Excellent answer!!

Comment: the answer is theological correct but not necessarily historically accurate. Many early OT texts show evidence of a 'henotheistic' attitude, in which the gods of other nations were considered real but the God of Israel is supreme. I will attempt an answer tomorrow that provides this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

@Anne writes: "Deuteronomy 10:17 is part of the consistent theme that there is only ever the one true God." The consistency of this theme is in the eye of the beholder. Historians of religion often recognize that early Israelite religion, including parts of the Torah, spoke of lesser gods as real. Typical of this school of thought are the writings of [Albrecht Alt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_Alt) a leading 19th century German theologian. [Nicholas F. Gier, Professor Emeritus, University of Idaho](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/ngier/henotheism.htm), summarized:

> The final editors of the Hebrew canon were fervent monotheists, but a
> remnant of the polytheistic basis of the pre-Mosaic religion can still
> be detected. Albrecht Alt has shown that divine titles such as 'El
> Bet' el (Gen. 31:13; 35:7); 'El 'Olam (Gen. 21:33); and 'El Ro'i (Gen.
> 16:13); 'El 'Elyon (Gen. 14:18); and 'El Saddai (Gen. 17:1); all later
> taken to be one God (Yahweh) after Moses, were all originally separate
> gods worshipped by the early Hebrews. The Catholic scholar Bruce
> Vawter concurs with Alt. According to Vawter, none of the available
> English translations does justice to the original Hebrew of Genesis
> 31:13, which quite simply reads "I am the god Bethel" ('El Bet'el),
> who was a member of the Canaanite pantheon along with the rest of the
> above.

The Bible is clear that it was forbidden for Israelites to worship other gods, but according to scholars such as those just mentioned, the idea that other deities simply did not exist evolved later and came to the fore especially during the period of the classical prophets (Isaiah, Jeremiah and Ezekiel). Scholars who support this perspective interpret verses such as Deuteronomy 10:17 and Psalm 136:2 as reflecting a version the earlier  [henotheistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henotheism) attitude, in which Yahweh is the supreme deity but not necessarily the only god. Just as the title "King of kings" does not deny the existence of other kings, "God of gods" does not necessarily deny the existence of other gods.

Other verses that support this view include:

- God has taken his place in the divine council; in the midst of the gods he holds judgment. - Ps. 82:1
- There is none like you among the gods, O Lord, nor are there any works like yours. - Psalm 86:8
- When the Most High apportioned the nations,
  when he divided humankind,
  he fixed the boundaries of the peoples
  according to the number of the gods... - Deut. 332-8
- I am the Lord your God, you shall have no other gods before me.  - Exodus 20:2-3

Translations of these verses vary, and interpretation also differ. However, they do lend a biblical basis to the idea that Israelite religion once recognized the reality of other gods.

**Conclusion**: Some scholars do deduce that the Israelites once thought the Lord was not alone among the gods. But this is different from saying that minor deities actually exist today. According to this perspective, the earlier scriptures taught that it was a sin for Israelites to worship any God but Yahweh, but other nations might worship other gods. Some verses imply the actual existence of these deities. However, Yahweh was supreme, and he alone was the God of the Israelites. By the time of the later prophets, this henotheistic attitude had evolved into the strict monotheism of mature Judaism and Christian tradition.

Comment: You lean on a 'school of thought' and promote it. That is not _hermeneutics_. Yet, surprisingly, you chide someone for 'theology'. 'Some scholars' is your stance, but I see no argument, here, from the _text_ of scripture.

Comment: Shouldn't a distinction be drawn between gods which 'exist' in human imagination and God who 'actually exists' even absent any humans at all.  It sounds as though certain scholars conflate the two.

Comment: @NigelJ - Schools of thought inform hermeneutics and vice versa. Thus one hermeneutical approach supports inerrantism while another supports historical criticism. I respect both approaches and do not downvote answers on the basis of approach as long as they are informative and well written. You may have missed the fact that I did not merely refer to "some scholars" but named and cited several examples. Those scholars provided an argument from scripture and I provided several other examples supporting a henotheistic interpretation.

Comment: Also.. when I referred to the "theological correctness" of @Anne's answer, I did not mean to chide...  My point is that IMO monotheism (which I agree with  because it is theologically correct) evolved out a polytheistic and henotheistic Israelite background.

Comment: The concept of one Divine Nature did not 'evolve'. God revealed himself. And men believed that revelation. You seem, to myself, to view these things from beneath, upwards. Which, to me, is incomprehensible.